# Layer based content filters aren't rendering in 10.8, either from Interface Builder or Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, core-image

In Lion and below you could use Interface Builder to turn on CALayers and then apply filters to a button, label, view, etc.  In 10.8 however, those UI elements simply do not render onto the screen.  In my testing programmatically setting a CALayer's contentFilters also makes it 'invisible'.

I've made a simple test project that shows this bug:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12790096/ContentFilterTest.zip

On Lion the test app looks like this:

[image: 10.7 test app screenshot]

On Mountain Lion the test app looks like this:

[image]

For reference, this is running on the GM build of ML, and built by Xcode 4.4 GM seed.

Comment: If you have a sample project that reliably displays this bug, file a bug report to Apple. It sure seems like a bug.

Comment: I filed a bug, #11912140, however in my experience Apple is very slow to respond to bug reports and this is something that I need to resolve ASAP.  I'll probably scratch my current implementation and do without in order to get my product to market.

Comment: Yes, they can sometimes take a very long time to respond to a bug report but it at least makes you feel like you did the right thing.

Comment: @Andrew - is not the GM build under NDA? Just a friendly remark, I'm not Apple...